# Correct query for update nested element MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Hi  i am new to mongoDB , i have a **order** collection like this .

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("11111111111111"),
    "stops" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("222222222222222"),
            "status" : "IN PROGRESS"
       },
       {
            "_id" : ObjectId("33333333333333"),
            "status" : "PENDING"
       }]
}
```

i want to update the stop status of the record for order `id = "11111111111111"` and 
stops `id = "222222222222222"` to done .

i searched in te interent and came up with a query like this

```
db.order.update(
    {'_id': ObjectId("11111111111111"), 'stops._id': ObjectId("222222222222222")},
     $set: {
            'stops.$.status': "DONE",
      }
);
```

My Question is

in the query it uses `'stops._id'` but when we update the field it uses `'stops.$.status'`

is it incorrect if i use `'stops.status'` ??

I have searched a lot in the internet and the answers and articles are confusing me .

so can anyone explain me what is the correct way and the difference between dot notation and the $ operator  .

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The $ operator acts differently depending on the context it's used in. In general, it is used in place of an array index.

Here, you're using it in an `update` query. This means you'll update the first element matching the search criteria. Here, your criteria is `{'_id': ObjectId("11111111111111"), 'stops._id': ObjectId("222222222222222")}`. It's okay to use `stops._id` without the $ operator because MongoDB will search for every element of stops that has the specified ObjectID (ie, it never required a specific index). When specifying the `$set`, the $ operator is telling MongoDB to update the *first* document in the array returned from the search. Since you're querying an array of documents, the return will *ALSO* be an array of documents, even if it's of length 1! In short, in `update` queries, the $ operator is used in place of a specific index. It should be noted that it can't be used if you're trying an `upsert` or if you're searching the array using a negation operator such as `$ne`.

In a `find` query, the $ operator is used in almost the same way. It will cause the query to only return the first element of an array (similar to a projection in relational DBs). It's worth noting that the $ operator is more limited when used in this manner. Only one $ operator can be used in the query, only one array can appear in the query, and only one condition can be evaluated.

It should be noted that in neither case can the $ operator be used for traversing more than one array or a nested array. To summarize, the $ operator is a more expressive way to access the first and only the first element of an array without specifying an index. You cannot use dot notation in place of it because you need an index. It is a good idea to use it when you know you'll always get arrays of length one or zero.

Official docs: [update query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), [find query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_).